# Meaning of "en" in "qu'elle ne voulut plus en porter d'autre"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, pronoms, en

Which part of speech (pronoun, preposition etc.) is "en" in this sentence, and what exactly is its contribution to the meaning of the sentence?

> Un jour, elle lui offrit un petit bonnet de velours rouge, qui lui allait si bien qu'elle ne voulut plus **en** porter d'autre.

The context in which the sentence occurs is this:

> Il était une fois une petite fille que tout le monde aimait bien, surtout sa grand-mère. Elle ne savait qu'entreprendre pour lui faire plaisir. Un jour, elle lui offrit un petit bonnet de velours rouge, qui lui allait si bien qu'elle ne voulut plus en porter d'autre. Du coup, on l'appela Chaperon Rouge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"En" is a pronoun and its use is essential to the meaning of the sentence.

If we chose not to use "en", the sentence would read as:

"Un jour, elle lui offrit un petit bonnet de velours rouge, qui lui allait si bien qu'elle ne voulut plus porter d'autre bonnet que celui-ci".

If we omit "en" altogether, the sentence is incomplete and does not make sense:

"Un jour, elle lui offrit un petit bonnet de velours rouge, qui lui allait si bien qu'elle ne voulut plus porter d'autre".

Comment: Thank you!  I'd never have thought of that in a million years.  If I may tack on a question like this, is 'Elle ne savait qu'entreprendre pour lui faire plaisir' idiomatic in French?  It's probably being translated from:  '...ihre Grossmutter, die wusste gar nicht, was sie alles dem Kinde geben sollte.'