# What is "en" replacing in "J’en ai la larme à l’œil."

Tags: grammaire, en

deepL translates "J’en ai la larme à l’œil" to "I have a tear in my eye" (or in more natural English, "It brings tears to my eyes").

I don't know what the "en" is there for. "J'ai mal à la tête" is a similar sentence, but it doesn't use an "en".

What is the "en" replacing in "J'en ai la larme à l'oeil"?

---

I saw "J'en ai la larme à l'oeil." in a reddit comment. I can't remember the rest of the context, but it was a very short reddit comment where "It brings a tear to my eye" made perfect sense.

---

**EDIT**

A user voted my question to be closed, because they claim that [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13205/meaning-of-en-in-quelle-ne-voulut-plus-en-porter-dautre) is a duplicate. I am now obliged to prove that linked question is not a duplicate of my question, in order to prevent my question from being closed.

- The linked question asks: "Meaning of “en” in “qu'elle ne voulut plus en porter d'autre”?".
- My question asks "What is "en" replacing in "J’en ai la larme à l’œil?".

The answer to the linked question says, in effect, "Given the context of the sentence you're asking about, the 'en' is required; the sentence would not make sense without the 'en' ".

My question is about an entirely different sentence, in an entirely different context. I, in fact, don't understand the answer in the linked question, and even if I did, it is not obvious how to apply it to my sentence.

Jst because two questions ask about the use of "en" in a sentence, doesn't mean that they are duplicates of each other and that one deserves to be closed.

Comment: Could you provide more context? From where does this sentence come?

Comment: As often "en" is a replacement for "de quelque chose".  Tu veux de l'eau? Oui, j'en veux. Tu est triste de la fin de cette émission? Oui, j'en ai la larme à l’œil.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/rance/comments/cyqsmf/joyeux_enfants_de_la_bourgogne/

Comment: @Dimitris it wasn't from that page (it was from a page that was in the last few days, maybe on r/Quebec, maybe on r/CanadianPolitics,; i wasn't able to re-find it). but i can say that that seagull in the page you linked to is funny :)

Comment: @XouDo so is it grammatically correct if i said "J'ai la larme à l'oeil de la fin de cette émission"?

Comment: @silph this sounds a little odd. You may says : "J'ai la larme à l’œil de voir la fin de cette émission" or "J'ai la larme à l’œil que cette émission soit finie".

Comment: @XouDo thanks for the feedback. it's a little difficult, as a French learner, to have to slightly modify the grammar rules we learn in textbooks, so that it stays applicable to actual real-life usage. ie the grammar rules in textbooks would say "en" replaces "de la fin de cette émission", but it can also replace "de voir la fin de cette émission".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of "en" in "qu'elle ne voulut plus en porter d'autre"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13205/meaning-of-en-in-quelle-ne-voulut-plus-en-porter-dautre)

Comment: @Toto No, it does not answer my question. I think people sometimes overestimate how easily language learners like myself can apply information written in other questions to help answer our own (often not-directly-related) questions. Just because a different question is slightly related or has a similar title, does not mean it is able to answer our question; and even if technically could answer our question, it often contains so much non-related information that us askers often need specific guidance to be able to understand the question with the similar title.

Comment: @Toto Not only does your linked question not answer my question, but *I myself asked about the linked question in a separate post, just twenty minutes before you voted to close my question*. I do not understand the answer linked question despite reading it carefully, so it cannot be a duplicate of my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*En* is a pronoun playing exactly the same role (i.e. referring to the same thing) than *it* in ***It** brings tears to my eyes*.

If you want to convert that to a *de + sth* sentence, that can be:

> *J'ai une larme à l'œil de voir ça.*

Comment: I am confused about this. I've learned that *en* replaces *de + noun*. The word "it" is usually translated using *Il*, or *elle* or *cela*, isn't it? Can you explain how "It" is translated with "en"?

Answer (score 0):

Une phrase similaire trouvée sur reddit [est](https://www.reddit.com/r/rance/comments/cyqsmf/joyeux_enfants_de_la_bourgogne/) :

> Je viens de voir le flair ban bourguignon, j’en ai la larme à l’œil.

En est un pronom qui se réfère à "le flair ban bourguignon", même si flair ne veut rien dire dans ce contexte. (voir commentaires qui suivent ma réponse ; merci @jlliagre et @Luke Sawczak.)

Comment: Qu'est ce qu'un "flair ban bourgignon"... mystère. Jargon de forum?

Comment: @XouDo Je ne sais pas du tout:-)! L'Op a modifié sa question en ajoutant où il a vu la phrase. J'ai cherché sur reddit et le voilà:-)! Si ma réponse est fausse je peux évidement l'effacer.

Comment: @XouDo ***Fier** ban bourguignon*, j'imagine.

Comment: @jlliagre Ma réponse, est-elle fausse ? Si oui, je peux l'effacer.

Comment: Non, ta réponse n'est pas fausse, *en* se réfère bien à *flair ban bourguignon*, même si *flair* ne veut rien dire dans ce contexte...

Comment: Non, il y a erreur, il n'y a rien à ajouter ; de plus, dans la phrase que vous introduisez, « en » ne réfère pas exactement à « le flair ban bourguignon » mais au fait « il a vu le flair ban bourguignon » ; il vaut mieux supprimer votre réponse.

Comment: It can clearly be parsed as referring to the seeing or to the thing seen. No error.

Comment: @LPH : jlliagre and Luke Sawczak (the former has proved many times to master the French language; the latter a teacher of French) contradict your assertion.

Comment: @Dimitris The « seeing of the  flair …» is what user Luke Sawczak  refers to, not the « flair », and therefore he confirms my contention.

Comment: @LPH "It can clearly be parsed as referring to the seeing **OR**  to the thing seen."

Comment: @Dimitris Je ne crois pas, il s'agit seulement  d'avoir vu la chose. Ensuite, il n'est aucunement question de phrase incomplète, à moins que vous vouliez dire que vous complétez la phrase dans le but de fournir une analyse, mais alors c'est exprimer la chose de façon horrible ; ce n'est pas du tout ce que les mots disent ; dans ce dernier cas il vaut mieux, au moins, modifier cette introduction.

Comment: @LPH Ce n'est pas seulement d'avoir **vu** le ban bourguignon qui a mis la larme à l'œil à la personne en question. C'est l'émotion suscitée par ce ban et elle n'est pas limitée au visible, le **son** de la chanson et les souvenirs associés font partie de ce **en**.

Answer (score 0):

Dans le cas présent d'utilisation de « en », doit précéder dans le contexte une situation qui cause de la peine aux gens en général et plus particulièrement à la personne qui parle. « En » réfère à

> ([TLFi, en²](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en))  **I. A. 1. a)** [cause, *à la suite de, à cause de*]
> ♦ Ainsi celui-là qui anéantit son ennemi. Et il vivait de lui. Donc il en meurt (Saint-Exup., Citad.,1944, p. 773).
> ♦ N'empêche que quand il m'a causé d'amour, j'ai eu comme un coup de langueur dans le poitrail. Encore maintenant, j'en suis toute chose (Aymé, Cléramb.,1950, III, 7, p. 168).

Si on reprend le dernier exemple on peut écrire ceci.

- N'empêche que quand il m'a causé d'amour, j'ai eu comme un coup de langueur dans le poitrail. Encore maintenant, je suis tout chose *à la suite de* cela.
- N'empêche que quand il m'a causé d'amour, j'ai eu comme un coup de langueur dans le poitrail. Encore maintenant, je suis toute chose **à la suite d'** avoir eu comme un coup de langueur dans le poitrail. (*On remplace le pronom « cela » par ce à quoi réfère « en ».*)

Voici l'autre possibilité, avec un sens similaire.

- N'empêche que quand il m'a causé d'amour, j'ai eu comme un coup de langueur dans le poitrail. Encore maintenant, j'en suis toute chose **à cause de** cela.

Donc, on n'a pas exactement la préposition « de » mais à la place des locutions qui la contiennent ; cependant, la raison pour cela est une question d'idiomaticité, car en fin de compte « de » en tant que préposition remplit cette fonction. On peut dire

- N'empêche que quand il m'a causé d'amour, j'ai eu comme un coup de langueur dans le poitrail. Encore maintenant, je suis toute chose de cela . (*« être tout(e) chose » signifie « avoir l'esprit troublé » (c'est un sentiment, une impression forte). Cependant cela n'est pas assez clair et ne se dit pas.*)

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de))  *De* exprime plutôt une action intérieure, ou le résultat de l'action, l'état, la situation.
> [De se rencontre après des verbes de sentiment.] Être aimé de, respecté de, estimé de, craint de (qqn).
> ♦ Touché des malheurs de son neveu, l'oncle Monetti promit d'améliorer sa position (Murger, Scènes vie boh.,1851, p. 61).Carpaccio, nous disent les historiens, fut pleuré de ses concitoyens (Barrès, Barbares,1888, p. 197)

On peut dire ceci à partir du dernier exemple : « Le neveu de l'oncle Moretti a eu des malheurs ; l'oncle Moretti en est touché. ».