# Can "en" replace a words that start with "que" instead of "de"?

Tags: pronoms, en

*(Note: This question essentially re-asks a question that is many years old, that already has an accepted answer. I figure it is better to re-ask the question, outlining why I don't understand the answer)*

---

In the textbooks that I've read, the pronoun "en" usually replaces a string of words, where the first word is "de" (or is the partitive article du/de la/des).

(The textbooks seem to say that the only exception is sentences that uses numerals like "trois" instead of "de", like "J'ai trois stylos" -> "J'en ai trois").

I've also recently asked a [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46567/what-is-en-replacing-in-j-en-ai-la-larme-%C3%A0-l-%C5%93il), where I learned that sometimes "en" seems to be replacing words that start with "de", but that these words are implied in ways that might not be obvious for a beginner language learner. For example, if someone says "J'en ai la larme à l'œil", this can be thought to stand for "J'ai la larme à l'œil *de voir ça*".

---

With this knowledge, I still cannot make sense of something written in the accepted answer in [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13205/meaning-of-en-in-quelle-ne-voulut-plus-en-porter-dautre) French.SE question.

The question was asking about what the "en" stands for in this sentence:

> Un jour, elle lui offrit un petit bonnet de velours rouge, qui lui allait si bien qu'elle ne voulut plus **en** porter d'autre.

The answer writes *(the bolding is added by me)*:

> "En" is a pronoun and its use is essential to the meaning of the sentence.
>
> If we chose not to use "en", the sentence would read as:
>
> "Un jour, elle lui offrit un petit bonnet de velours rouge, qui lui
> allait si bien qu'**elle ne voulut plus porter d'autre bonnet que
> celui-ci**".
>
> If we omit "en" altogether, the sentence is incomplete and does not
> make sense:
>
> "Un jour, elle lui offrit un petit bonnet de velours rouge, qui lui
> allait si bien qu'elle ne voulut plus porter d'autre".

The person who wrote the question accepted the answer, and seems to understand the answer. But I don't understand the answer! It seems that the "en" is replacing "que celui-ci", which confuses me.

Questions:

1. I'm confused about that "en" is replacing "que celui-ci". Is it really replacing "que celui-ci"?
2. The answer says that without the "en", the sentence is incomplete and doesn't make sense. (ie it is saying that ".... elle ne voulut plus porter d'autre" doesn't make sense). But it seems to make sense to me. Why is the sentence incomplete and not make sense?

Comment: porter d'autre bonnet: porter is followed by d'. One can avoid repeating "porter d'autre bonnet" by using en.  **Elle portait des** jolies perles roses. Elle en portait des roses. See? :) The en substitutes the jolies perles.

Comment: @Lambie I'm a little bit confused right now about "des roses" or "d'autre" staying, because I haven't seen this before. I'm not sure why it's not "Elle en portait **de** roses" if it's correct to say "Elle ne voulait plus en porter **d**' autre"; or why it's not "Elle ne voulait plus en porter **des** autres" if "**des** roses" is correct. But this is a more minor confusion; the main idea I learned is that *en* can avoid repeating an entire string of words starting with "de" or the partitive article, but leave some of those words in the sentence.

Comment: Elle portait "des jolies perles roses": the EN replaces the phrase that comes after de. She wore pink ones = Elle en portait des roses. The other sentence is: she no longer wanted to wear any other [bonnet]. = ne plus en porter d'autre. Now, I realize you are working through a non-native language which makes this even trickier.

Comment: @Lambie I understand "Voici les jolie perles roses" "Ah, elle en portait!". But I'm still trying to understand "Voici les jolie perles" "Ah, elle en portait des roses!". I understand "Voila mes souliers. J'en portes chaque matin". But I'm still trying to learn "Voila mes souliers neufs. Mais j'en portes d'autres chaque matin". (Assuming I even understood this new use of *en* well enough, in these example sentences!)

Comment: Ok, last time: Since porter is FOLLOWED by de, d', des, de l', to avoid repeating what comes after those determiners, you use EN. en portait des roses just means: the pink **ones**. You have to remember that somewhere there is porter DE something, even if implied. The reason you say: J'en portes chaque matin, **is not because of** Voilà mes souliers. It's because we say: On porte DES souliers. And it is not Voici les jolies perles roses that takes EN. It's because of porter **des** jolies perles roses.

Comment: @Lambie actually, the fact that it is always "porter *de* qch" when talking about wearing something, might be one thing I didn't understand, which adds to the confusion. Please don't be angry with me if I ask a separate question about that. I appreciate your attempts to help me understand, but if it's not working, it's because i'm too stupid and need even more idiot-proof explanations.

Comment: The verb "porter", with the sense given to it in the present context, is transitive (porter qch): https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*En* refers to the whole expression *autre bonnet (que celui-ci)*, not just *que celui-ci*.

Without *en*, the phrase becomes:

> elle ne voulut plus porter d'autre.

This indeed is incomplete because there is no indication about what *autre* is referring to. Maybe does "She no longer wanted to wear some other" work in English but in French, we need to tell some other "what".

Without *d'autre* but with *en*, the sentence is grammatical:

> *elle ne voulut plus en porter.*

but its meaning is different. She no longer wants to wear any *bonnet* at all.

Comment: may i say that *en* refers to *d'autre bonnet (que celui-ci)* (that is, with the *d'*)? i want to say that, to make *en* fit with the pattern the textbooks tell me. The new thing that I've learned is that *en* can replace a string of words, but that you might have to keep some words in (because with "Elle ne voulut plus en porter", the reader doesn't have enough information to know that the *en* includes *d'autre*"). Can you write some other example sentences in your answer, where *en* replaces "de + _____ ", but some of the words in "de + _____ " are left in the sentence?

Comment: Reading your comment and observing that *d'autre* is already in the sentence, I guess I should have written that *en* only refers to *bonnet* with *que celui-ci* being implicit.

Comment: @jiliagre: then this confuses me, because now it's a new rule for *en* that I don't understand! I learned that *en* almost always replaces "de + ____ ". So now I don't understand the rule that lets *en* replace only *bonnet*. If a pronoun would only replace *bonnet*, wouldn't it be *le*, as in "elle ne voulut plus le porter d'autre"?

Comment: @silph The en avoids having to repeat the word bonnet twice, why? Because porter here *takes* de.

Comment: *En* only replaces *bonnet* because *de* is already there in *d'autre*.

Comment: Note that the following sentence works though: ***Elle ne voulait plus en porter d'autre de bonnet !***

Answer (score 1):

Upon re-reading a part of the book "The Structure of Modern Standard French" by Maj-Britt Mosegaard Hansen, I realize that I grossly misunderstood the use of *en*. It is far too simplistic to say that *en* usually replaces "de + _____".

The following excerpt applies to my question (but there are other uses of *en* discussed in the book) :

> In addition, *en* is frequently used to represent only the head noun
> of an indefinite noun phrase, leaving both the determiner and any
> modifiers behind, as shown in (30)-(31) below. This is possible no
> matter what kind of indefinite determiner is used:
>
> (30) Un *train* peut **en** cacher un *autre*. ( = Un train peut
> cacher [un autre *train*.]) (31) A: Je pourrais te piquer une
> cigarette, s'il te plaît ? B: Oui, mais je n'**en** ai que des
> *légères*. ( = Oui, mais je n'ai que [des *cigarettes* légères.]).
> (from Section 17.2.2 in "The Structure of Modern Standard French")

It is worth reminding myself that some indefinite determiners are:

- Indefinite Article
- Partitive Article
- Numerals

(from Section 12.1, "Definite and Indefinite Determiners")

Given the above information, how *en* is used in the sentences below now makes sense. The only thing I still must do, is to make sure I understand why "d'autre bonnet que celui-ci" and "des jolies perles" are considered indefinite noun phrases.

- Elle ne voulut plus porter *d'autre [bonnet que celui-ci]*
  Elle ne voulut plus *en* porter d'autre
- Elle portait *des [jolies perles] roses*.
  Elle *en* portait des roses.