# Différence entre « ne ... que » et « ne ... que ... seul »

Tags: adverbes, différence

Y a-t-il une différence entre

> Il n'y a qu'une caisse dans cette épicerie

et

> Il n'y a qu'une seule caisse dans cette épicerie

? Est-ce que la deuxième phrase porte plus d'accentuation ? Toutes les deux sont correctes ?

Car j'ai rencontré une phrase qui s'écrit « le genre humain courbé sous la honte *ne* doit avoir *qu'* un *seul* étandard », et je songe que peut-être il y a une différence subtile sur cette locution.

Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 3):

Il n'y a pas vraiment de différence. Le sens est exactement le même. Ajouter « seul » rend la phrase plus longue, donc il y a plus d'insistance, mais l'effet est très faible.

La construction « ne … que » est un peu bizarre en français : c'est une négation, mais elle est différente des autres négation. « Il n'y a pas/plus/jamais/… de caisse » signifie qu'il y a 0 caisse, alors que « il n'y a qu'une caisse » signifie qu'il y a une caisse.

Ajouter « seul » peut rendre la phrase plus facile à comprendre, voire non ambiguë. En français relâché, on peut dire « Il y a qu'une caisse » (ou plus vraisemblablement « Y'a qu'une caisse »), et la négation n'est portée que par le mot « que » qui a beaucoup d'autres sens, et à l'oral par le son [k]. Avec « seul », on ne risque pas de mal entendre. Il y a même quelques cas où la phrase pourrait être ambiguë :

> Il y a qu'une caisse, c'est peu.

Grammaticalement, la phrase pourrait s'analyser comme équivalente à « Il n'y a qu'une seule caisse. C'est peu. » ou « N'avoir qu'une caisse est une petite quantité. » Dans ce cas le sens est à peu près le même, mais on doit pouvoir trouver des cas plus tordus où le sens diverge.

En français plus ancien, aujourd'hui seulement dans un français très littéraire, on peut avoir une négation qui n'est indiquée que par le mot « ne ». [Cela rendait l'ambiguïté plus courante](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46577/does-ne-que-sometimes-not-mean-only/46582#46582).

Answer (score 0):

L'ajout de cet adjectif n'est qu'une question de renforcement, celui d'une restriction ; ce type de phrase est parfaitement correct.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/seul)) − [Renforce une restriction]
> ♦ N'avoir qu'une seule envie, ne faire qu'une seule remarque.
> ♦ Il n'y avait qu'une seule expression qui à tous leur fût commune: l'absence de fierté.  (Montherl.,Célibataires,1934, p. 837)